# What does it mean to have two colors in the fill section?

Tags: inkscape, color, fill

What does this fill color mean? How did it come up? What is the use of it? There is no explanation in both [The Fill and Stroke Dialog — Inkscape Beginners' Guide 1.0 documentation](https://inkscape-manuals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fill-and-stroke-dialog.html) and [Inkscape tutorial: Basic | Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/doc/tutorials/basic/tutorial-basic.html).

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The checkerboard in the left and cyan in the right show that you have cyan fill color, but it's fully transparent. The left half shows the degree of the transparency. There's no difference, if the color is fully opaque i.e. alpha=100.